# React Martial UI component overwritten/conflicts when new component is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I am talking about a big web app that has jquery and bootstrap stuff init.
Part of rewriting this giant app using react and material UI, we are writing component by component. Things work fine in general as we make progress toward making this a react app soon.

**Our problem:**
When a new react component is loaded into the page, the existing (already loaded) react components will lose some or all styles.

We checked the new component load new style (classes) which are matching the names of existing classes for other already loaded components.
Ex:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, jss1, jss2, ... MuiCardHeader, MuiGrid, ... were also the names for the previously loaded components and now they are overwritten for the newly loaded component.

**Packages.json:**

[image]

**webpack config:**
[image]

**Some component code:** we are using make style and in some cases withstyle
[image]

Tried too much stuff. But nothing seems to work. On initial load, the map has all the correct material-ui stuff but as soon as I click on a marker and the popup component loads in. Now the map is messed up as some styles are overwritten.

How can we make it so that each component styles are named unique and never conflicts with other stuff?
I checked  MUI docs and GitHub issues about kinda similar issue but nothing is working for us.

Any thoughts?

If I add:

```
import { StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const generateClassName1 = createGenerateClassName({
    seed: 'App2',
});
```

my custom classes ( like root, mydivstyle) will have the prefix like app2-jss1-root, app2-jss2-mydivstyle, ...
but muiCard, MuiCardHeader, ... still being overwritten.

Comment: Not 100% sure but it could be possible if you not passing the name as second param to `withStyle` or `makeStyle` in functional component,  try this `withStyles(styles, { name: "YouUniqueComponentName" })`.
more info [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/)

Answer (score 1):

So after a few trial and error. I was able to solve this.
Basically we don't have a component tree path where you can could add a single class generator because of our app structure at this stage. We will soon have one.

The solution was to wrap every component like.

```
import { StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    seed: 'anyprefix',
});

class ActivityContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                    <componenet/>
            </StylesProvider>
        );
    };
}
```

I had to do this on the container level, this way any component loaded in that container will inherit this prefix.

No more conflicting class names between components and can load them dynamically.
Not a great way but no other option at least in our case. It will leave more classes on the DOM.